# Sending SQL Results to Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a program that runs an SQL Query, and i'd like to report it to a crystal report viewer.  I am receiving the error:

```
DataSourceException was unhandled: The report has no tables
```

My code is:

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=Main;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=login;Password=password")
        Dim CategoryAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT firstname, lastname, add1 from Customers where dtcreated between @startdate and @enddate", con)
        Dim ProductData As New DataSet()
        con.Open()

        CategoryAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 130
        CategoryAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Startdate", DateTimePicker1.Value)
        CategoryAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enddate", DateTimePicker2.Value)

        CategoryAdapter.Fill(ProductData)


        Dim objRpt As New CrystalReport1
        objRpt.SetDataSource(ProductData.Tables(0))
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
        Return ProductData.Tables(0)
        con.Close()

        con.Dispose()
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You need to apply datasource to report at time of design. Store your SQL output in dataset and convert dataset into XML and apply xml to your Crystal Report at time of design report. So next time whenever your run your code XML automatiocally generate any applied as input data table of your crystal report.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the report file in objRpt before to set datasource
objRpt .Load(filepath)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I applied your recommendation, it didn't work.